# Creación de un trigger para validación

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy en el **consecutivo** **1070039332**, como se ve en la imagen. Pero no puedo dejar que pase del **consecutivo** **1070039400**, no tengo mucha experiencia con triggers.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código:

```
create trigger restrinccion on [dbo].[tblencfacturas] for update 
as 
declare @ consecutivo int 

select @consecutivo = count(tblencfacturas.consecutivo) 
       from tblencfacturas 

if (@consecutivo>=1070039400) begin 
    print 'No se puede realizar la Factura, restrinccion sistemas.' 
end
```

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado?

Comment: create trigger restrinccion 
on [dbo].[tblencfacturas]
for update 
as 
declare @ consecutivo int
select @ consecutivo = count(tblencfacturas.consecutivo) from tblencfacturas
if (@ consecutivo>=1070039400)
begin
print 'No se puede realizar la Factura, restrinccion sistemas.' 
end

Comment: pero no me funciona

Comment: Y que error te tira ese trigger?

Comment: El `print` no es una condición de error, deberías invocar a `raiseerror`

Comment: @PatricioMoracho tiene razón. El `print` solo muestra un mensaje en pantalla. Debes realizar una acción (además del `print`). Un `raiseerror` es una alternativa. Todo va a depender de lo que quieras que ocurra al cumplirse la condición que dispara el `trigger`.

Comment: no saca error solo que deja pasar todo normal no hace nada me pueden ayudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que el `print` en caso de error no dispara ninguna excepción, por consiguiente la transacción puede ejecutarse sin problemas. Lo que deberías hacer es generar un error mediante `RAISEERROR`

Por ejemplo:

```
create trigger restrinccion on [dbo].[tblencfacturas] for update 
as 
declare @ consecutivo int 

select @consecutivo = MAX(INSERTED.consecutivo) 
       from INSERTED

if (@consecutivo>=1070039400) begin 
    RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar la Factura, restrinccion sistemas.',
                                             -- Message text.  
               16,                           -- Severity.  
               1                             -- State.  
               ) 
end
```

Detalles:

- *Severity*: O nivel de severidad puede ser configurado por el usuario usando los niveles 0 a 18.
- *State*: Un entero de 0 a 255, normalmente usado para indicar de alguna manera dónde ocurrió el error

Estos dos parámetros pueden ser útiles si eventualmente se capturan los errores para tener un control más fino sobre estos.

#### Notas adicionales

Modifiqué tu código, ya que entiendo que lo que buscas es saber si se está intentando agregar un valor de `consecutivo` superior a un límite, lo que estabas haciendo, `select @consecutivo = count(tblencfacturas.consecutivo) from tblencfacturas` no iba a funcionar:

- Solo te retorna la cantidad de filas con valores distintos de `consecutivo`
- Además solo tiene en cuenta las filas actuales y lo que necesitas es verificar la filas que se están intentando insertar o actualizar

Para el último punto, existen en los triggers, pseudo tablas `INSERTED`  o `DELETED`, con la primera obtenemos las filas con los valores que vamos a actualizar. De modo que podemos hacer:

```
select @consecutivo = MAX(INSERTED.consecutivo) 
       from INSERTED
```

Con lo que obtenemos el mayor valor de `consecutivo` que queremos actualizar o insertar, hay que tener en cuenta que un trigger se ejecuta a nivel lote, por lo que bien puedes actualizar una fila o múltiples, la sentencia anterior es consistente con cualquiera de estas formas.

Como bien señala Lamak, en MSSQL no hay una instancia de `BEFORE UPDATE` para un trigger, por consiguiente siempre la actualización será realizada, el error es un evento posterior a esto. Por esto, siempre que quieras manejar un trigger inhabilitante deberías manejar una transacción y mucho mejor un bloque `TRY .. CATCH ..`, en cuyo caso el `RAISEERROR` puede ser capturado y deshechada toda la transacción. En tu ejemplo, para que el trigger funcione tal como esperas que lo haga, deberías hacer algo así:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
BEGIN TRY

    update tblencfacturas set consecutivo = 1070039400 + 1

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION        
    PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE() -- Capturamos el mensaje del trigger

END CATCH
```

Comment: Pero este error se lanza una vez que ya se insertaron los datos, por lo que no está impidiendo nada...

Comment: @Lamak, es cierto lo que dices, pero si estás dentro de una transacción puedes "rollbaquearla". Agrego esa aclaración.