# Creación de un trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy en el **consecutivo** **1070039332**, como se ve en la imagen. Pero no puedo dejar que pase del **consecutivo** **1070039400**,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

he intentado con este trigger pero no me funciona

```
USE [bases]
GO
/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[restrinccion]    Script Date: 19/02/2019 11:09:18 a. m. ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[restrinccion] 
ON [dbo].[tblencfacturas] 
FOR INSERT 
AS
DECLARE @consecutivo CHAR(20)

IF (@consecutivo>=1070039333) BEGIN 
    RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar la Factura, restrinccion sistemas.',
                                             -- Message text.  
               16,                           -- Severity.  
               1                             -- State.  
               ) 
END
```

Comment: Falta obtener el valor de `@consecutivo`.

Comment: Revisa la edición de mi respuesta anterior: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239032/creaci%c3%b3n-de-un-trigger-para-validaci%c3%b3n,  que creo que respondería tu duda de fondo.

Comment: Además hay que considerar que este trigger está usando sólo `FOR`, lo que por defecto lo convierte en un `AFTER` trigger...vale decir, se ejecuta una vez que ha terminado exitosamente el `INSERT` que lo gatilló...lanzar un error ahí no tiene sentido

Comment: Esta pregunta es exactamente igual a la otra hecha por otro usuario. Tal vez algun ejercicio?

Comment: @gbianchi es tan igual...que ambas nombran al trigger como `restrinccion` en vez de `restriccion`

Comment: ya he modificado muchas veces y ninguna me sirve no se que es

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que dentro de un trigger no es posible recibir parámetros como en un procedimiento almacenado. La variable @consecutivo en tu trigger no toma ningun valor por lo tanto, nunca se realiza la validación que tienes.

Primero debes acceder al valor del campo "consecutivo" que se acaba de registrar, para ello puedes utilizar las tablas temporales INSERTED o DELETED en SQL Server o bien los objetos temporales NEW y OLD en MySQL.

Ejemplo en SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @consecutivo CHAR(20)
SELECT @consecutivo = consecutivo FROM INSERTED;
```

Otro error por el que posiblemente no sirva tu validación es porque almacenas el valor en una variable de tipo CHAR y en tu condición lo tratas como un entero. Primero convierte el valor de char a un valor entero, prueba con lo siguiente:

```
DECLARE @consecutivoEntero INT;
SET @consecutivoEntero = CONVERT(int, @consecutivo)

---CONTINUAS CON TU VALIDACIÓN

IF (@consecutivoEntero>=1070039333) BEGIN 
   RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar la Factura, restrinccion sistemas.',
                                         -- Message text.  
           16,                           -- Severity.  
           1                             -- State.  
           ) 
END
```

Nota: Si no debes dejar que consecutivo pase de 1070039400, entonces tu condición es incorrecta. En dado caso seria IF @consecutivo > 1070039400
De esta forma todo aquel que sea mayor, se le mostrará el mensaje de error "No se puede realizar la factura, restricción sistemas".

Comment: Tu ejemplo para SQL Server asume que sólo se insertó una fila en la tabla. En caso contrario, se asigna un valor en `@consecutivo`, pero arbitrario

Comment: Un trigger solo se ejecuta después de un evento sobre una tabla de la base de datos. En este caso, se ejecuta después de una inserción de datos sobre la tabla "tblencfacturas". Si no se registra nada, el trigger no tiene porque ejecutarse por lo tanto, siempre la tabla temporal INSERTED deberá contener los ultimos datos de la fila registrada, no existe un caso contrario. En la pregunta publicada no se especifica si solo se desea mostrar el mensaje pero si insertar los datos o bien impedir su registro en caso de no cumplir con la condición, en ese caso se debe usar INSTEAD OF en lugar de AFTER.