# ¿Cómo usar un trigger para inhabilitar una operación?

Tags: sql-server

Estos días se ha estado preguntando en distintas oportunidades y de distintas formas como usar triggers en sql-server para hacer distintas validaciones, por ejemplo: [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239425/impedir-insertar-con-trigger), [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239096/creaci%C3%B3n-de-un-trigger) y [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239032/creaci%C3%B3n-de-un-trigger-para-validaci%C3%B3n), esa pregunta es un intento para sintetizar las distintas dudas que hay alrededor del tema.

La idea es sencilla, ¿de que forma se puede usar un `trigger` para inhabilitar por ejemplo una sentencia de `INSERT`?. Digamos que tenemos una columna numérica en una tabla y no queremos que el valor supere un cierto límite. (Hay otras formas de resolverlo sin usar triggers, pero se trata de un ejemplo).

```
create table Ejemplo ( consecutivo int )
go
```

Lo que queremos es no dejar insertar valores superiores a 20 en la columna `consecutivo`, por ejemplo, esto debería funcionar:

```
insert into Ejemplo(consecutivo) values (1)
```

pero esto ya no:

```
insert into Ejemplo(consecutivo) values (21)
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Creación de un trigger para validación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239032/creaci%c3%b3n-de-un-trigger-para-validaci%c3%b3n)

Comment: @Lamak, la idea que tengo es marcar como duplicada la otra

Comment: Cerrremos las otras como dup de esta.

Comment: Listo @gbianchi, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay dos puntos importantes que hay que tener en cuenta:

- En SQL Server no disponemos de un `trigger` del tipo `BEFORE <evento>`, es decir no podemos validar la condición antes del realizar el `INSERT` (o cualquier otra operación)
- El `trigger` se dispara por el lote completo de filas actualizadas y no por fila única, por lo que siempre la lógica del `trigger` debe contemplar esto y nunca suponer que es una sola la fila a la que aplica.

Básicamente hay dos formas:

## Usar un `trigger` y disparar un error y un `rollback`

Esto funciona desde las versiones más antiguas de `SQL Server`, la idea es validar la condición dentro del `trigger` y en caso de no cumplirse, emitir un error y realizar un `ROLLBACK`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER restriccion ON [dbo].[Ejemplo] FOR INSERT 
AS

    DECLARE @consecutivo INT

    SELECT @consecutivo = MAX(INSERTED.Consecutivo) 
           FROM INSERTED

    IF (@consecutivo > 20) BEGIN

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar la inserción, restricción de negocios.',
                                                 -- Message text.  
                   16,                           -- Severity.  
                   1                             -- State.  
                   ) 

    END
    GO
```

Al intentar insertar

```
insert into Ejemplo(consecutivo) values (21)

Server: Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure restriccion, Line 13
No se puede realizar la inserción, restricción de negocios.
Server: Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.
```

Puntos importantes:

- Las validaciones las hacemos sobre las filas insertadas no sobre la tabla física, para esto usamos la pseudo-tabla `INSERTED`.
- Fundamental el `ROLLBACK`, como ya dijimos la validación se hace "a posteriori" del `INSERT`, por lo que es mandatorio deshacer la operación
- El `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` funcionará aún si no hemos abierto explícitamente una transación, el `trigger` siempre estará dentro de una transacción implícita
- Otra forma, es dejar el `ROLLBACK` afuera del trigger y "decidir" que hacer en una capa posterior, por ejemplo:

  ```
  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO Ejemplo(consecutivo) VALUES (21)
      COMMIT TRANSACTION
  END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
      ROLLBACK TRANSACTION        
      PRINT ERROR_MESSAGE()  
  END CATCH
  ```

Si hemos quitado el `ROLLBACK` al `trigger`, solo generaremos el error, que podremos "capturar" en una instancia superior mediante un `TRY .. CATCH` y decidir que hacer luego.

## Reemplazar completamente el evento de `insert`

O al menos eso es mas o menos esta idea. Si mal no recuerdo, a partir de `SQL-Server-2008` se incorporó la clausula `INSTEAD OF` para los `triggers`, definir un `trigger` de esta forma implica que nos deberemos hacer cargo del proceso completo de inserción en la tabla física. Por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER restriccion ON [dbo].[Ejemplo] INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

    DECLARE @consecutivo INT

    SELECT @consecutivo = MAX(INSERTED.Consecutivo) 
           FROM INSERTED

    IF (@consecutivo>=20) BEGIN

        RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar la inserción, restricción de negocios.',
                                                 -- Message text.  
                   16,                           -- Severity.  
                   1                             -- State.  
                   ) 

    END ELSE BEGIN

        INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Consecutivo)
        SELECT  Consecutivo
            FROM INSERTED

    END
GO
```

La idea es simple, si se da la condición de error, emitimos un `RAISEERROR` y fin del asunto, caso contrario, es decir, valor `válidos`deberemos hacer el `insert` de la tabla física desde la pseudo-tabla `INSERTED`. Ahora si ejecutamos el `insert` conflictivo

```
insert into Ejemplo(consecutivo) values (21)

Server: Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Procedure restriccion, Line 13
No se puede realizar la inserción, restricción de negocios.
```

Obtenemos mismo mensaje de error y por supuesto no se han insertado filas por que en el `trigger` al darse esta condición, no hemos pasado por el `insert`.

Podremos agregar un `ROLLBACK` dentro del trigger, pero en este caso ya no sería necesario al menos para evitar la inserción en esta tabla en particular, pero si podría ser útil para deshacer automáticamente una transacción mayor

Answer (score -1):

este trigger lo valide y funciono correctamente no me deja pasar ningún consecutivo después del 20 y deja pasar el resto muchas gracias <3

CREATE TRIGGER restriccion ON [dbo].[Ejemplo] FOR INSERT 
    AS

```
    DECLARE @consecutivo INT

    SELECT @consecutivo = MAX(INSERTED.Consecutivo) 
           FROM INSERTED

    IF (@consecutivo > 20) BEGIN

        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
        RAISERROR ('No se puede realizar la inserción, restricción de negocios.',
                                                 -- Message text.  
                   16,                           -- Severity.  
                   1                             -- State.  
                   ) 

    END
    GO
```