# Impedir insertar con trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

necesito hacer un trigger que me impida insertar cuando haya un registro especifico, es decir que si tengo un consecutivo que va en el 10, cuando llegue al 20 no deje pasar mas consecutivos a partir de este,
intentando con este trigger funciona pero no deja insertar ni el 11,12,13..., tengo que dejar pasar del  10 al  20 y cuando vaya insertar el  21  este no lo deje me pueden ayudar con la solución o que tengo mal muchas gracias

```
CREATE TRIGGER prueba 
  ON [dbo].[tblencfacturas] 
  instead of insert
as  
BEGIN
    IF (SELECT consecutivo FROM tblencfacturas
        WHERE consecutivo >='20') ='20'
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblencfacturas]  (consecutivo) (select consecutivo from inserted)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        raiserror('registro NO agregado', 10, 1) 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END
```

Comment: Esta pregunta no la hicieron ayer, con otros numeros, dos veces?

Comment: @gbianchi, si https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239032/creaci%C3%B3n-de-un-trigger-para-validaci%C3%B3n, evidentemente no quedó nada claro.

Comment: o tienen que terminar todos el ejercicio por separado.. :/.. cerremosla por dup...

Comment: @Server, tienes varios problemas: Algo conceptual, en sql server los triggers se disparan luego del insert real, por lo que no se pueden usar para inhabilitar una operación, a menos que desde tu aplicación uses transacciones, esto quiere decir que antes de ejecutar el insert en la tabla hagans un `BEGIN TRANSACTION`, entonces un `RAISEERROR` puede ser el disparador para hacer un `ROLLBACK`. El `ROLLBACK` es mejor usarlo fuera del trigger y siempre (obvio) que exista una transacción abierta anterior.

Comment: Ayuden no la cierren

Comment: `SELECT consecutivo FROM tblencfacturas  WHERE consecutivo >='20'`, ¿por que las comillas¿ ¿no es un numérico? ¿Por que lees `tblencfacturas`?, no le encuentro sentido, las filas insertadas ya las tienes en `INSERTED` ¿Por que vuelves a intentar insertar en `tblencfacturas`? Bien, creo que todo parte de una confusión inicial acerca de como funcionan los triggers en sql-server.

Comment: @Server, por que no vas a la pregunta duplicada de esta y tratas de entender la respuesta que ya existe y en todo caso haces algún comentario con tus dudas ?

Comment: por que ya leí y no me quedo nada claro y no se como resolverlo :(

Comment: @gbinachi, voy a tratar de armar un pregunta respuesta más genérica para detallar las soluciones posibles, y poder responder de paso a Server.

Comment: muchas gracias @PatricioMoracho <3

Comment: @Server, mira a ver si esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/239471/c%C3%B3mo-usar-un-trigger-para-inhabilitar-una-operaci%C3%B3n/239472#239472, responde a tus dudas. Saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho muchas gracias amigo ahora si me funciono gracias gracias